# In object oriented programming, should inanimate objects have methods/behaviour?

Tags: oop

I am a new user to programming and have started learning object oriented programming. It seems OOP is used to model real-life objects and interactions.
My question is, should inanimate objects have behaviour?

For example should I have something like

```
class Room:
    clean()

or

class User:
    clean_room(Room)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! You should have both.

The room can definitely have a clean() method, even if it's inanimate. In fact, this is practically necessary. If you pass a room to the User they will still have to call some public method in the Room class to perform the cleaning. clean() would be a suitable method for this. In fact, *public* methods exist so they can be used from the outside of the class, by some other class.

To be able to tell the User that he/she should clean the room, you also need a clean_room() method in the User class. This method will then call the clean() method on the Room object.

Comment: Thank you, is this referred to as delegation when I am "forwarding" the clean_room call to room.clean?

Comment: The simple "forwarding" to room.clean() is actually called just that: "Forwarding". Many people use the terms forwarding and delegation interchangeably. But delegation is strictly speaking a different concept where an object acts on behalf of another (knowing which object called the function).

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the difference between forwarding and delegation: [Difference between forwarding and delegation](https://knowledge-capsule.site/en/difference-between-forwarding-and-delegation/). You can also check out this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816011/in-oop-what-is-forwarding-and-how-is-it-different-from-delegation)